# Odd Xcode behavior when creating classes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, templates, interface, xcode4.2

When I go into xcode try to add a new class with File>New>New File and then adding an Objective C class, my header file winds up looking like this:

```
@interface Course : NSObject 

@end
```

instead of what it needs to look like

```
@interface Course : NSObject {
@private

}
@end
```

is there any reason for this, I'd really like to have it set up the way that the code snippet does (the second) by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is normal behavior for Xcode 4.2. The new runtime does not require the creation of instance variables when you use properties.

Old runtime:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
  NSNumber *myNumber;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumber;
@end;
```

New runtime:

```
@interface Foo: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *myNumber;
@end;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.  I do not see where he is asking about instance variables or properties in his question.

Comment: @chown The OP has asked if there’s a reason why the new templates do not have a `{@private}` block (for ivars).

Comment: @Bavarious Ohhhhhhh, I get it, you'r answering the *why* part.  I read his statement: "I'd really like to have it set up the (2nd) way by default" as his main question.  But, this does provide an answer for the *why* part; sorry about that =).

Comment: So the Objective C runtime changed that quickly. In the books and videos i'm using everything looks different now

Answer (score 3):

In the

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Cocoa Touch/Objective-C class.xctemplate/NSObject
```

directory there are template files called `___FILEBASENAME___.m` and `___FILEBASENAME___.h`.  What you need to do is change the `___FILEBASENAME___.h` file (using something like vim, TextWrangler, etc) from this:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
//

___IMPORTHEADER_cocoaTouchSubclass___

@interface ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ : ___VARIABLE_cocoaTouchSubclass___

@end
```

To this:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
//

___IMPORTHEADER_cocoaTouchSubclass___

@interface ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___ : ___VARIABLE_cocoaTouchSubclass___ {
@private

}
@end
```

Poke around in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/` and `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates` to see more templates you can customize.

Or use this python script I wrote to customize them all automatically (after tweaking the python script to fit your customization needs):
http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/20/easy-xcode-template-customization/